# Is there a standard way to prepare lyrics for a singer?

Tags: music, production, vocals

I'm making some electronic music, and would like to prepare it for vocals. I know what the vocals are and where they should go, but would like to know if there is a standard way to prepare it for a singer? Or if not, a standard way the recording process is usually done?

Comment: As a starting point, perhaps you should add how you do it now.

Comment: Right now, we're just adding a track (in ableton) with the notes we want the lyrics to be. We haven't actually done it yet though, we're getting ready to talk to some singers, and was just wondering if there was a regular way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, people write a score including the lyrics and the notes. For electronic music, you can write the singing part in MIDI, convert the MIDI to a score (MuseScore does it very well using MusicXML), add lyrics (ith the same MuseScore), and send the score. It's when people will read and sing the score that you can judge their voice quality and ability to read a score :)
As for the recording process : If you can rent a studio for a few hours, go to it with the music (without lyrics) already pre-mixed and pre-mastered and ask for the signer to sing over the music while you record what he/she sings. Then you will have some big files including the result, choose the best, edit it with the rest of your music (you can put effects on the voice, but use EFFECTS and only EFFECTS). Hope this helps :)